# How to tell a request from a response in a JAX-WS handler?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I know I can use `MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY` to determine if the message is inbound or outbound, but if I have a service that calls other services, and I am using a generic handler to log all the messages, that does not tell me if the message is a request or a response.

For example, an `INBOUND` message could be a request coming into my service or a response coming back from a service I've called.  An `OUTBOUND` message could be a response from my service or a request going out to a service I'm calling.

Is there any way to know if a `SOAP` message is a request or response?

Thanks.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I wonder if I could check the HTTP Response headers.  A response from a service I called should have them, whereas a response I'm sending back probably won't...

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this and found no better method than separating handlers into a Client handler and a Server handler.

That way, they can just use their respective outbound properties to see whether something is a request to server/from client or a response to client/from server.